# Google Maps API v3 pathing with location service

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

I'm using Google Maps for my campus map and I already have all the overlays for the buildings done along with javascript to open windows when clicked on the overlay, etc. The next problem I'm trying to tackle is how to get directions from point A to point B (using point A as geolocation).  On my campus there is about 2.5 miles+ of sidewalks but they aren't defined paths in google maps, so i cannot use the built in directions which Google maps offers.

Is there any way i can make it so it displays directions from point A to point B while making it so it displays a path along a sidewalk?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I already have the geolocation working also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Google doesn't know about the sidewalks, you will have to do the drawing yourself.  You will need to store information about the sidewalks in a database, then come up with a routing algorithm, then draw a line (using the Polyline class).

For routing algorithms, you might be able to get away with using Dijkstra's algorithm
   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm
or you could try A*
   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm
or one of the other algorithms you can find in the Wikipedia sidebar on the Dijkstra and A* pages.

Polyline documentation:
   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Polylines